# Como insertar un string en un array de dos dimensiones

Tags: array, c, string

Hola buenas tengo el siguiente problema, quiero insertar la palabra que se genera al hacer la permutación de esta y guardarla en un arreglo de dos dimensiones, pero el problema es que no sé cómo hacerlo, intente agregarle como entrada a mi función la matriz generada pero el problema es que no lo guarda y al utilizar un debugger me dice "Segmentation fault (core dumped)",quizás porque no supe como declarar bien la matriz dentro de la función, si me pudieran dar una mano con esto estaria muy agradecido.
Este es mi codigo, deje comentado donde deberia ir:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int factorial(int largo){
    if(largo==1)
        return 1;
    else
        return factorial(largo-1)*largo;
}
int tamano(char palabra[]){
    int tamanio=0;
    while (palabra[tamanio]!='\0')
        tamanio=tamanio+1;
    return tamanio;
}
void intercambioLetras(char *a, char *b){
    char aux;
    aux=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=aux;
}
void permutar(char *palabra,int i, int largo){
    int j;
    if (i==largo){
    /*Insetar la palabra en la matriz*/
    /*###############################*/
        /*printf("%s\n",palabra);*/
    }
    else{
        for (j=i; j<=largo;++j){
            intercambioLetras((palabra + i),(palabra +j));
            permutar(palabra,i+1,largo);
            intercambioLetras((palabra + i),(palabra +j));
        }
    }
}
int main () {
    printf("Ingrese una palabra de a lo mas 6 letras: ");
    char palabra[8];
    scanf("%s",palabra);

    /*generar el largo de la lista*/
    int largo,filas,i;
    /*largo representa a la cantidad de columnas que tendra la matriz*/
    largo=tamano(palabra);
    filas=factorial(largo);

    /*generar la matriz para almacenar las palabras generadas tras realizar la permutacion*/
    /*filas representa a las permutaciones -1*/
    char **matrizPalabras;
    matrizPalabras=(char**)malloc(sizeof(int)*filas);
    for (i=0; i< filas;++i){
        matrizPalabras[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*largo);
    }
    permutar(palabra,0,largo-1);

    /*Mostrar las palabras permutadas*/
    /*for(i=0;i<filas;++i){
        printf("%s",matrizPalabras[i]);
    }
    */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido Jorge.

Has intentado con tomar el tamaño del puntero al reservar espacio para la matriz?

```
matrizPalabras=(char**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*filas);
```

El `sizeof` debería tomar el tamaño del puntero `int*`, no del `int`, ya que eso es lo que almacenas por N filas.

Comment: Hola Pablo, al parecer ese era el problema por el cual no podia asignar valores en la matriz, muchas gracias.